# Help identifying resistor with arrow accross and capacitor with unit "kp" or "k" or value "5/6"

Tags: capacitor, resistors, symbol, units

Can you please help me identity these symbols from a vintage (1960) diagram?
The capacitors units are noted with "KP", sometimes just "K".
What is the rectangle crossed with an arrow? It looks like a potentiometer without the tap connected.

**1.what does kp means? pico farad?**

[image: Capacitor with "680 kp"]

**2. what is this symbol? 5/6?**

[image: Capacitor with the broad terminal partially clamping the short one; unit "5/6"]

**3. 47K farad?**

[image: Capacitor with "47 K"]

**4. 22k resistor or diode or bias pot?**

[image: Resistor or pot or even a diode?]

The full circuit:
[image: Full circuit (source)]

Comment: `47K farad?` ... no. :)

Comment: 680 kilo-pico farads?

Comment: Likely 47000pf = 47nf and 680 nf. The arrows indicate potentiometers or variable resistors (use a pot, connect the wiper to one end). The other one looks like an electrolytic capacitor but "5/6" makes no sense as a value - is it perhaps the 5th section of a 6-section capacitor? (Packing several high voltage caps into one can used to be common, in the pre-transistor days). The full circuit may give enough context for a better guess.

Comment: i added the full diagram. thanks! I guess you right, trimmer, kilo-pico but the electolytic capacitor is the last enigma... 5/6 maybe of a standrd common uf value??

Comment: How about 5uF/6Vdc, the voltage requirement is quite low

Comment: Compare the 5uF/6Vdc at the input to the 5uF/12Vdc at the output. The voltage requirement at the output collector is somewhat higher than at the input...

Comment: Seeing the circuit, yes the electrolytics are 5uF/6V and 12V, from the days when 12V electrolytics were larger and more expensive than 6V ones. As for the shape? The negative terminal is usually the outer can.

Comment: kilo picofarad = nF. People where not sane in the membrane back in the 60s and 70s.

Comment: Isn't that battery upside down?  (The stack of lines)

Answer (score 2):

1. capacitor 680 kilo-pico-Farad (kpF) same as 680nF
2. Capacitor 5uF 6Volt.
3. 100k ohm potentiometer
4. 22k ohm trimer potentiometer

All capacitors marked k are in kpF which is the same as nF
The line inside the resistors means that those are thin film resistors either carbon or metal.

This is a NPN BJT based circuit, GND is connected to the positive of the battery and negative terminal is marked + but GND should be negative despite teh battery symbol being wrong.

Comment: 1) Electrolytic cap: I agree about the value of 5uF / 6V but the small terminal should be positive; the large terminal should be negative. 2) Transistors appear to be NPN. Google also thinks that the transistors are NPN. 3) There is a really good chance that the capacitor marked "680kp" is 680nF Polystyrene (low leakage and very stable). – Dwayne Reid 7 hours ago

Comment: Yes you are right, I have updated the answer.

Comment: I think the + sign is on the right side but the battery is upside down.

Comment: That is correct, the thin and long line in the battery symbol is the plus terminal, but the symbol is upside down